# How do I migrate my Google Calendar & Contacts to Outlook.com?

Tags: google-calendar, google-contacts, outlook.com, migrate-data

I want to migrate my calendar and contacts from Google to Outlook.com

Outlook.com offers [an easy "one-click" service to transfer your mail](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2013/12/11/outlook-com-makes-it-even-easier-to-switch-from-gmail.aspx) but this doesn't migrate your calendar and contacts.

If there anyway that I can do this?

Being on WebApps, I'd obviously like to avoid as much manual intervention as possible so a web app/service would be the preferred option :)

Comment: Well, the [official Outlook method](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/transfer-contacts-between-outlook-and-google-gmail-HA010222048.aspx#BM1) for contacts is export to CSV and import from it into Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook.com documentation contains an article to [import contacts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/import-contacts-into-an-outlook-com-account-HA104051344.aspx). The article also described how to import from Gmail.

> **Add Google Gmail contacts or contacts from a .csv**
>
> The smoothest way to use Gmail contacts in Outlook.com is to add them on the Outlook.com website.
>
> You can also use the Outlook.com website to add contacts from a .csv file. (For Outlook.com accounts, using Outlook to import the .csv won’t work.)

See [the article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/import-contacts-into-an-outlook-com-account-HA104051344.aspx) for full details.

There are also details about [importing a calendar](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/calendar-import-vs-subscribe). Export it from Google Calendar and import it into Outlook.com.